# Mongo update to many query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

does anyone know how to change a propertie value in mongo
from

i changed JSON.units[0].services[0].label from etiket controle to AuditLabel

i tried this:

```
db.getCollection('assortiment').updateMany({"units.$[].services.$[].label": "etiket controle"},{ "$set": { "units.$[].services.$[].label": "AuditLabel" }})
```

but no succes because it dont select anything

```json
{
    "_id" : "764",
    "meta" : {
        "groupsId" : "764",
        "type" : "DRYGR"
    },
    "units" : [ 
        {
            "unit" : "BASE_UNIT_OR_EACH",
            "gtin" : "08711728556206",
            "services" : [ 
                {
                    "label" : "etiket controle",
                    "collection" : "gtins"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

to

```json
{
    "_id" : "764",
    "meta" : {
        "groupsId" : "764",
        "type" : "DRYGR"
    },
    "units" : [ 
        {
            "unit" : "BASE_UNIT_OR_EACH",
            "gtin" : "08711728556206",
            "services" : [ 
                {
                    "label" : "AuditLabel",
                    "collection" : "gtins"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: if you dont need to search, and you already know the indexes like the `JSON.units[0].services[0].label` you can do something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8K5tXfWU0_y) you can remove the search if you want to update it in any case,  but i think you don't want this, and you want to update the label in any place, but not sure

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70049488/2282634

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its work's for me

```
db.getCollection('assortiment').updateMany(
  {
    "units.services.label": "etiket controle"
  },
  {
    "$set":
      { "units.$[].services.$[].label": "AuditLabel" }
  }
)
```